# How can I remove 'Search' and 'Update' buttons from subgrid of jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, subgrid

I am looking for jqGrid option that can hide 'Search' and 'Update' buttons of subgrid. (Marked in red circle)

[image]

Comment: I'm not at work right now so i dont have the file on me at moment, but i can get you more info monday if thats ok. Anyway, you'll need to look for specific lines in the js file and alter them to suite your needs. I love jqgrid, and have actually fully modified the code to suite our customers needs including adding a hidable search to the top of the grid rather than going to the bottom. it's kinda annoying they dont make these things more accessable, but you really have 2 choices, fix it at the source, or create some later script to do more work to remove/hide these items at run time.,

Comment: Of course i havn't updated to the newest version, and from what my roomie just told me, the newest version is supposed to have a the option to disable these menu items if needed.

Comment: SpYk3HH, thank you for response. I use the latest version of jqGrid and of course it would be better to find solution without editing source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you use [subgrid as grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) feature of jqGrid. See on [the demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) example under "Advanced"/"Subgrid as Grid".

Inside of `subGridRowExpanded` you create explicitly new grid (as subgrid) and can *optionally* create navigator buttons with the line like

```
$("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',
    "#" + pager_id, {edit: false, add: false, del: false});
```

So you should just remove the line or add additional options `search: false` and `refresh: false`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Could you please specify where this options were mentioned in jqGrid documentation?

Comment: @Yara: You are welcome! The description of the parameters of `navGrid` function you can find [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#parameters).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pagination" ></div>
```

jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagination',{del:false,add:false,edit:false,search: false, refresh: false},{},{},{});